# Php login. What if 2 computers connext to the same login page. Will $_SESSION VARIABLE BE OVERWRITTEN?

Tags: php, authentication

I am a beginner to php. I created a login page. It works perfectly fine but I have a doubt if 2 users login together the Session variables will be changed to the  details of the 2nd user. When I tried this in 2 tabs in a single computer it happened. Unfortunaltely I have only 1 computer at my house so can anyone tell me this will happen if i run it through multiple computers.

```
 // SOME DETAILS HIDDEN
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "Select * From user Where UserId = '$uid' And Password = '$pass'");            

while ($x = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    if ($x['UserId'] == $uid){
         $_SESSION['Fname'] = $x['Fname'];
         $_SESSION['Lname'] = $x['Lname'];
         $_SESSION['userid'] = $x['UserId'];
         // SOME MORE HIDDEN            
     } else {$err = "Invalid Entry";} 
}
```

Comment: fire up two different browsers and test your code

Comment: session depends upon `user agent` (Browser) not on computer, you can install multiple browser and every browser will have unique session

Comment: Or open Incognito Mode in Chrome... it's good for more than just porn!

Answer (score 2):

When a session is started following things occur:

1. A unique identifier is created. It is a random string of 32 hexadecimal numbers.
2. A cookie called PHPSESSID is created and saved on the user's computer. The unique session ID is that cookie's value.
3. A file is automatically created on the server in the temporary directory. The file name is prefixed with sess_ and then the unique session id that was created.

This process is unique to each browser's connection to the php script. So, two users will have different session ids and you code will execute as expected.